# Tor and Submarine communications cables

Tags: anonymity, circuit, onion-routing

According to the papers leaked by Snowden, the NSA has the ability to intercept communications carried by submarine cables.

My question is: does Tor also use these submarine cables? So, can Tor be monitored through surveillance programs like PRISM or Upstream?

Edit:

Imagine that the NSA has intervened all submarine telecommunication cables. I suppose Tor uses these cables. So, could the NSA spy on Tor's communications in this context?

(Forgive my English, English is not my mother tongue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can monitor the cable or the wireless packets, but they're encrypted, so to actually monitor the tor traffic you need to defeat the encryption algo at least three times in a row - because by default Tor uses 3 hops and so it makes a three-layer onions.

Comment: No. You need to defeat it at least once, at most three times and possibly not at all. This is an, at best, incomplete (and wrong) answer to a misguided question.

Comment: so, enlighten us, how precisely? intercepting cables means eavesdroping, i.e. a passive attacker. Catching unencrypted traffic on the exit node is a different problem, so how exactly "can Tor be monitored through surveillance programs like PRISM or Upstream" just using cables intercepting? I'm curious

Comment: Intercept ingress and egress traffic, Tapping undersea cables nets a large percentage of international comms data. Correlate ingress and egress traffic, tie unencrypted egress traffic to ingress traffic. See plaintext, no decryption required.

Comment: unencrypted traffic IS insecure, so nothing to do with the undersea cables. The question was about how undersea cables that can be monitored can be a potential security risk. To properly implement corellation attacks(bandwidth watch) monitoring just these cables is not near enough to succeed. And speaking of Tor security the only potential risk is to catch Tor packets coming overseas: and all the private data in Tor are traveling in onions, so unless you can decrypt them - no risk of just intercepting any carrier, not just cables, data transmitted via Tor are safe

Comment: Let's imagine the following:

Imagine that the NSA has intervened all submarine telecommunication cables. I suppose Tor uses these cables. So, could the NSA spy on Tor's communications in this context? Or, at least, could the NSA spy unencrypted information through submarine cables? Notice that I am now asking only for submarine cables.

(Forgive my English, English is not my mother tongue).

Comment: They just carry traffic. If the traffic was sent across the cable, of course they could see it. Encrypted traffic is still revealing, HTTPS won't help. It's why people use Tor instead of just HTTPS on it's own.

Comment: unencrypted traffic IS wiretappable, in any carrier, not just in undersea cables. Yes, in that case they will have all the unencrypted traffic passing through, in active intrusion case they will be able to spoof it as they wish. In case of Tor communications: directory information - from a cache node or dirserver itself is signed, keys are hardcoded in the source code, no spoof available, this info is not secret/private. Other Tor communications are in 3-layered crypto onions, so they can dump a ciphertext(the whole onion, not a message + route) but can not open it and intercept. Via any cable

Comment: 1/2 Imagine this example: I am using Tor to communicate with a foreign friend. The information is traveling through submarine cables. To chat with my friend, I'm using a web page with HTTPS protocol. Now, imagine that the NSA detects submarine cable traffic, could the NSA see the message I'm sending? 1/2

Comment: 2/2 I know the NSA probably could not reach me, because Tor routed my web traffic through 3 nodes. The question is about the content of the message itself. Could the NSA see the content of the message? I also want to ask the following: If the NSA has intervened (imagine) all underwater telecommunication cables, is it still safe to use Tor in combination with the HTTPS protocol? (Assuming the NSA has not yet developed a tool to break SSL / TLS encryption) 2/2

Comment: 1/2 - no, they can not see the message: even if it travels not in Tor but from exit node - there's still HTTPS to protect you and your message contents. Use a decentralized HTTPS certificate validation and you are fine. 2/2 yes, it's safe: intervention means eavesdropping, i.e. traffic dumping, and onions are encrypted. So taking the assumption of non-existense of https breaking tool - tor+https combo is a right thing to use